# What is the benefit importing React, {Component} instead of just React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

What is the major benefit of writing

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Link extends Component {
   ...
}
```

instead of

```
import React from 'react';
class Link extends React.Component {
   ...
}
```

when it comes to react 15.4.x??

In **my perspective** and **in my case** (correct me if I am wrong) it does not matter at all since:

1. I am using a `webpack2` for making my bundles;
2. I use code splitting to split my app code from vendor code;
3. I use `webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin` plugin with `minChunks: Infinity` setting to make sure that all vendor code is included only once.

From understanding how ES6 imports work I understand that by using named import of `{Component}` I state that I want to use only `Component` component in my code, which looks.. cleaner.
But since whole `React` package is still used in the app, I can create my classes with extension from `React.Component` instead of just `Component` and in result webpack will still produce the same amount of code and my bundle size will be the same in both cases.

Am I correct?

Comment: it's a matter of preference (for example I prefer `Component` instead of `React.Component` notation)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no difference, `React.Component` is the same object as `Component`, the second way is more eloquent in my opinion, because it really explains that you are using the `Component` object from the `React` library.

The first one seems to refer a member, 
but, it comes from the `pre modules era` of javascript, where everything had to be attached to the exported global namespace (just to avoid global namespace pollution).

---

something that could be under the hood:

```js
// this should be assumed as an example only.

class React { ... }
class Component { ... }


React.Component = Component;

// ES6
export {Component}
export default React;

// ES5
window.React = React;
```

Note: as someone said, you also need to import `React` because `JSX` needs to have it on scope, but, if you want to avoid it, you can expose `React` globally (`window.React = React`)

Answer (score 8):

This import statement:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

is really doing two things. It imports the `default` export, under the name `React` (which is just a convention, you could call it what you want). It also imports a named export, `Component`.

The reason that the default `React` is imported is actually to make JSX work. When your JSX code is transpiled, then it substitutes `<div>` for `React.DOM.div()`, so `React` must exist otherwise things break!

Importing both things separately means that your JSX works but you get to write `Component` instead of `React.Component` in your code.

When you do `import` anything `from "react"`, then the whole file is going to get included either way - any attempt to reduce the bundle size (e.g. Dead Code Elimination, Tree Shaking) is an additional, separate step, which doesn't depend on your import statements but the parts of the code that you use.

---

In the case of this library, the sane thing happens: the child `Component` of the default export refers to the same thing as the named export `Component`.

However, bear in mind that this isn't guaranteed to be the case! If the React library code contained the following:

```
export default {
    Component: "foo"
};

export const Component = "bar";
```

Then `React.Component === "foo"` and `Component === "bar"`.