# What is the correct way to import things from React?

Tags: reactjs

Which way from these two below is the correct way to import things from react? I'm seeing both regularly everywhere, even in React documentation:

```
import React from 'react';

export class MyComponent extends React.Component { }
```

or

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class MyComponent extends Component { }
```

Is there any difference between them? Maybe in the second one the final code will be smaller?

Comment: Read this explaination - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44516436/what-is-the-benefit-importing-react-component-instead-of-just-react

Answer (score 0):

The following way of importing is better and it has advantages like code usability because if we create multiple component, then we dont need to extend with React.Component, we can use Component directly.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class MyComponent extends Component { }
```

Comment: I have one component per file, so this is not an advantage for me. I was more interested in performance advantages.